# System error on your website

Tags: discussion

I Am brand new to this website and the system has mistakenly locked me out of posting any messages. Without knowledge of how the rules work, I posted a new question at the following URl:

[Is there one body of common law?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/is-there-one-body-of-common-law)

I was under the impression that my question was a direct continuation of the thread. I had learned about your website from a Google search. However, one of the administrators did not appreciate that I asked the question in that thread and asked me to re-ask the question in a new thread. I did re-ask the question in a new thread.  However, the system has now locked me out and is not allowing me to post any messages at all. There is no way I can fix this problem and it is preventing my proper use and participation on your website.

Is there a way somebody could fix my account so that I can properly participate? This seems to be an inadvertent error of your website as I had no intention to post anything that was of low-quality or was considered beyond the rules of the website

Comment: For the starter, Stack Exchange is not a forum, but a Q&A site: ask a question, get answers. Using "Answer" as "Reply" is a mistake (coming from forum users). Take a [tour] for brief introduction of this site.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a system error. You are not blocked from posting questions.

I asked you *twice* to ask your question as a new question, not as an answer to an existing question.

The correct way to reference the existing question is to link to it in your new question.

On your first deleted answer, BlueDogRanch commented:

> You need to ask your questions and make your points in a new question that references this old, answered question, not ask your question as an answer to this question. See https://law.stackexchange.com/help

And I commented:

> If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

On your second deleted answer - with the same content - feetwet commented:

> This is a fine *new* question.  Please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button.  You can include [a link to *this* question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1686/is-there-one-body-of-common-law) if it helps provide context.  Since what you wrote here is a *question posted as an answer* we will have to delete it if you don't do so yourself.

After 15 hours, I deleted your second answer.

If you are new to the website, I suggest you firstly look at the Help Center.

The following section may be of use to you:

- [Why and how are some answers deleted?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/deleted-answers)

  > Answers that **do not fundamentally answer the question** may be removed. This includes answers that are:
  >
  > - commentary on the question or other answers
  >
  >   - asking another, different question
  >   - “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
  >   - exact duplicates of other answers
  >   - barely more than a link to an external site
  >   - not even a partial answer to the actual question
- [How do I ask a good question?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

---

As an aside, I note that you think this is an *Australian* website; this is not the case.